# SSL certificate problem : self signed certificate in certificate chain in Android studio

Tags: android, ssl, bitbucket

I am new to Bitbucket, while clone the source code from Bitbucket to Android Studio getting the following error.

Repository test failed.
Unable to access ..... : SSL certificate problem : Self signed certificate in certificate chain.

[image]

Can Any one help me, How to solve the issue.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: What you crossed the url and directory for - these are clearly visible in error message ;)

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? If so, what was the solution?

Answer (score 0):

That URL is for Bitbucket Server, which means that somebody in your organization is the administrator and should therefore be able to answer your question.